# calling methods of one class to another : Android

Tags: android

I have two java files Main and New. In main i have a number methods from oncreate to surface destroyed. on clicking one of the button it goes to New. There i have called the same `xml` file. But no methods are working there. i want to call the oncreate method including all methods from New. Please help

```
 public class Main extends Activity implements  SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
      ...............}

        buttonStartCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {......}
         });

      testButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent nextIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),New.class);
            startActivityForResult(nextIntent,301);
        }
        });
```

**Second** class

```
     public class New extends Activity
    {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
       setContentView(R.layout.main);


   }
}
```

Comment: you want new to behave the same way as main??

Comment: One way is to create static methods but i am not sure i get what you need to do!

Answer (score 1):

Your second class name is `NewActivity`

but Your intent is calling different class.

Comment: then paste it as it is, and clarify what are Your trying to do and what is the problem, not just "it is not working".

Comment: i want to call a method from another class like...function of buttonstartcamera in main has to be called from New class

Comment: Then You have to create an instance of this class or make this method static. But which one it is in Your situation I don't know. But I know that You should do a bit of reading on OOP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a base activity that both `MainActivity` and `NewActivity` extends and put methods in it.

For ex:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{



   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
  ...............}

    buttonStartCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {......}
     });

  testButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent nextIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(nextIntent,301);
    }
    });
    }


    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{
    onCreate..
    {
      ...

    }
    }


    public class NewActivity extends BaseActivity{
    onCreate..
    {
      ...

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

->`Intent nextIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),New.class);`

replace to

```
Intent nextIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewActivity.class);
```